# Twilio Voice API: Remove participant from conference and redirect to TwiML

Tags: php, twilio

How can I kick a participant from a running conference, and instead redirect him to some TwiML / another URL on my server? In the Twilio documentation, I found this to remove a participant from a conference (PHP):

```
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid    = "AC45245425c2bfac9ca2d3a101e4728d05";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$twilio->conferences("CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
       ->participants("CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
       ->delete();
```

However, as per [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#delete-a-participant-resource) there's no option to specify an URL with TwiML. The participant simply gets completely kicked from the call.

Is there any option to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the participants CallSID and modify it to point to new TwiML.

[Modify Calls In Progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress)